# Vue js iterating through data sub-properties is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and I am trying to bind an element with a fairly complex data object using Vue with a nested component.

I believe I have set this up correctly according to the documentation but I'm not seeing any examples that match my situation exactly.

The error I'm getting is `vue.js:584 [Vue warn]: Property or method "factions" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`  This message is displayed for every json object property that is referenced in the markup.  I'm guessing there is something relatively simple here that I'm missing but I cannot determine what that is.  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rjz0gfLn/7/

And the code:

```js
var x = {
  "factions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Unknown",
      "img": "Unknown.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Light",
      "img": "Light.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Dark",
      "img": "Dark.png"
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Unknown",
      "img": "Unknown.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Assassin",
      "img": "Assassin.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mage",
      "img": "Mage.png"
    }
  ],
  "cacheDate": 1521495430225
};

console.log("data object", x);

Vue.component("filter-item", {
    template:   `<li class="fitem">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="fcheck" />
                    <img :src="img" class="fimg" />
                    <span class="fname">
                        {{name}}
                    </span>
                </li>`});

Vue.component("filter-items", {
    template: `<ul class="flist">
                    <filter-item v-repeat="factions"></filter-item>
                    <li class="fseperator"/>
                    <filter-item v-repeat="roles"></filter-item>
                </ul>`});

var v = new Vue({
  el: "#filters",
  data: x
});
```

```html
<nav id="filter-drawer">
  <ul id="filters" class="flist">
        <filter-items></filter-items>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare **every** data you want to pass to the children as `props`  in those child components. Additionally you need to pass each prop from the parent using `:fieldnameinchild="value"` (shorthand for `v-bind:fieldnameinchild="value"`.

In your case, you'll need to do that in several places:

Parent:

```
<filter-items :factions="factions" :roles="roles"></filter-items>
```

And child:

```
<filter-item v-for="f in factions" :img="f.img" :fimg="f.fimg" :name="f.name" :key="'f'+f.id"></filter-item>
<filter-item v-for="r in roles" :img="r.img" :fimg="r.fimg" :name="r.name" :key="'r'+r.id"></filter-item>
```

Notice, in vue2 you want to use `v-for` instead of `v-repeat`.

Also, add `:key` to the `v-for`:

> [Vue tip]: : component lists rendered with `v-for` should have explicit keys. See https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#key for more info.

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/rjz0gfLn/21/

```js
var x = {
  "factions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Unknown",
      "img": "img.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Light",
      "img": "/a/a6/Light.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Dark",
      "img": "/0/0e/Dark.png"
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Unknown",
      "img": "img.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Assassin",
      "img": "/6/69/Assassin.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mage",
      "img": "/2/20/Mage.png"
    }
  ],
  "cacheDate": 1521495430225
};

console.log("data object", x);

Vue.component("filter-item", {
    template:   `<li class="fitem">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="fcheck" />
                    <img :src="img" class="fimg" />
                    <span class="fname">
                        {{name}}
                    </span>
                </li>`,
  props: ['img', 'fimg', 'name']
                
});

Vue.component("filter-items", {
  template: `<ul class="flist">
               <filter-item v-for="f in factions" :img="f.img" :fimg="f.fimg" :name="f.name" :key="'f'+f.id"></filter-item>
               <li class="fseperator"/>
               <filter-item v-for="r in roles" :img="r.img" :fimg="r.fimg" :name="r.name" :key="'r'+r.id"></filter-item>
             </ul>`,
  props: ['factions', 'roles']
});

var v = new Vue({
  el: "#filters",
  data: x
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<nav id="filter-drawer">
  <ul id="filters" class="flist">
        <filter-items :factions="factions" :roles="roles"></filter-items>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`factions` belongs to the root Vue instance, `filter-items` has a different `data` object.  You probably want to pass in `factions` as a prop to `filter-items`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

```
Vue.component("filter-items", {
    props: ['factions'],
    template: `<ul class="flist">
                <filter-item v-repeat="factions"></filter-item>
                <li class="fseperator"/>
                <filter-item v-repeat="roles"></filter-item>
        </ul>`});


var v = new Vue({
  el: "#filters",
  data: x
});
<nav id="filter-drawer">
  <ul id="filters" class="flist">
        <filter-items :factions="factions"></filter-items>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

EDIT: `v-repeat` was deprecated, use `v-for`, and you're not passing a prop down to `filter-item`